# WSANOTINITIALISED (10093) error on close when moving VS project file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, winsock

I have a large project consisting of a main executable and 3 DLLs.

DLL1 is a server application that acts as an interface between the main executable and the other 2 DLLs and handles all of the UDP communication between the them.

DLL2 and DLL3 are nearly identical and share source files within the Visual Studio solution.  These 2 DLLs use UDP to talk to each other and to DLL1.

The project was nearly complete (and working) and I was doing some cleanup which involved moving DLL3 directory (containing VS project file) up one level.  I wanted to make the directory structure more intuitive to the user.

No other code changes were made.  The program now executes fine until destructors are called at the end of the program at which time I get error 10093 (WSANOTINITIALISED) when sockets are being closed.  I call WSAstartup once at the beginning and WSAcleanup once at the end.  WSAcleanup has not yet been called when I see these errors.

There are no code changes, the only difference is the location of the project.  Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked that `WSAStartup` actually succeeds? Show that code. Make a RAII class for `WSAStartup` / `WSACleanup`.

Comment: Which module is doing the cleanup?  If it's one of the DLLs doing the cleanup: _"...at end of the program"_  you may have inadvertently changed the DLL unload order.

Comment: Clearly the sockets are being closed after `WSACleanup()` is called, despite what you claim, but we can't see the code that actually performs all of this cleanup.  Each DLL that uses WinSock should be making its own calls to `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()`. Or else move the calls to `WSAStartup()` and `WSAcleanup()` to the main EXE and don't call `WSACleanup()` until after the DLLs are unloaded and have closed their sockets.